# I want to check if all values in one column of a dataset are bigger than the means of that column

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I want to check all values in a column against one value(means) of the same column and then split into two lists.

```
means = np.mean(X[0], axis=0)
X = df.iloc[:, :4]
```

How can I check if values of X[0] are <= or > than the mean and split these values into two?

```
print(X.head(5))
print(np.mean(X[0].head(5),axis=0))
```

[image: Output from code above:]

Comment: can you post the sample input and expected output

Comment: Did you try `X.to_numpy() <= means`? This would return an array of booleans which you could later use for splitting?

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_0':[3.6,4.5,3.8,3.4,0.3],
                   'col_1':[8.6,8.1,-2.6,9.5,-4.4],
                   'col_2':[-2.8,-2.4,1.9,-4.0,4.5],
                   'col_3':[-0.4,-1.4,0.1,-3.5,-0.9]})

# Filter out rows where column is less than or equal to mean
# create list of values for first column
greater = df[df['col_0'] > df['col_0'].mean()]
greater_than_list = greater['col_0'].to_list()

# Filter out rows where column is greater than the mean
# create list of values for first column
less = df[df['col_0'] <= df['col_0'].mean()]
less_than_list = less['col_0'].to_list()


print(greater_than_list)
print(less_than_list)
```

output:

```
greater_than_list 
[3.6, 4.5, 3.8, 3.4] 

less_than_list 
[0.3]
```